# Defining my function inside or outside the class

Tags: reactjs

So, this is just a best practices question.

If I have a create class like:

```
class Example extends Component {
  method = () => {
    return 'hello';
  }
}
```

Versus:

```
methodFunction() {
  return 'hello';
}

class Example extends Component {
  method = () => {
    return methodFunction;
  }
}
```

What are the major differences? I get that if I need access to `this`, I won't have it in the `methodFunction` unless I pass it in. But, are there any other `scope` related gotchas to moving my functions outside of the class?

Also, I'm curious because, I'd like to move all the functions outside of the class. Seems like it would be easier to test functions this way.

Let me know what you think,
Cheers!

Comment: If your method isn't related to the class it shouldn't be in the class, just like any other programming. (Marginally) easier to test and use elsewhere. That said: this is an opinion, which isn't really SO material--you could just as easily argue that if it's tightly coupled too the class it should be in the class (although most linter defaults will complain if it doesn't "need" to be there).

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks Dave. What if, the only connection this method has to the class, is it does something with `this.props`... could it still be argued to move the function out of the class and just pass in the props that are needed?

Comment: But _why_ would you have a class like what you're showing? Why isn't that a normal `class Example extends Component { constructor(props) { super(props); } method() { ... } ... }`? Why the arrow function? Class functions always have access to `this`, provided you call them on the correct object (the biggest offender here is people using `onClick={this.somefunc}` instead of `onClick={evt => this.someFunc(evt)}`, which people tend to "fix" by shadow-rebinding in the constructor, which is basically the opposite of what classes are for)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the class is just an example to illustrate what I'm proposing... having functions be inside files instead of inside classes. The arrow function helps to avoid passing new closures to subcomponents. This way, you can just pass the method, avoiding an unnecessary re-render of the subcomponent if it was a react component.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I don't understand your comment--rebinding doesn't "go against" what classes are for, it's simply providing an instance method on instantiation, which is the same thing as an arrow function, and it's one things constructors are for: creating instance variables.  I'd argue creating a new function every render is worse.

Comment: Hi, best practices questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow as they are primarily opinion-based.